# LANケーブルの帯域と速度の関係について

Tags: network

LANケーブルのcat5eとcat6は通信速度は同じ1Gbpsですが、帯域幅は100Mhz,250Mhzと違います。
帯域幅が広いほど通信速度が速くなるはずですが、なぜ、帯域幅の広いcat6がより狭いcat5eと同じ速度しか出せないのですか？
速度は同じでも帯域幅が広いと何か利点があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1Gbps以上だと、cat6は1000BASE-T、1000BASE-TX、10GBASE-Tに対応してます。cat5eは1000BASE-Tにしか対応してません。

もともと1000BASE-TX用という感じでしたが結局普及しなかったのです。のちに、10GBASE-Tにも対応しました。